# No API - run search?

Tags: python, api, rest, module, search-engine

I'm writing a program (in Python) that takes inputted data and then runs the string through a website. Problem is, the website doesn't have an API.

Is there anyway that I can work with the website without an API? Specifically, with this website: http://forebears.io/search

Basically, my flow would be:

-calls website
-runs input through search 
-outputs most prevalent country

So for example, if you input was "Lopez" I'd want "Mexico" as the output.

Comment: But searching for "Lopez" on that site doesn't yield anything containing "Mexico"...

Comment: http://forebears.io/surnames/lopez I want the most prevalent country to be output, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah well, that's a different page that what I got...

Comment: Look into 'requests' library to make http requests.  Then use regular expressions to rip the data out of the response. Be-warned, sometimes websites don't include API because they don't want you automate use of their website and servers.  Sometimes you have to pay for API.  Perhaps e-mail them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try watching the network tab in your browser as you make the request, see if you can access the endpoint it uses externally (or can you curl it or even just open it in a browser) and if you can use that for your call.